# Flutter/Dart which architecture for App and potentially web app?

Tags: android, ios, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

**Question:**
So I heard of many different approaches to structure flutter apps and it just really overwhelmed me.

There is MVI or MVU or MVP-based architectures, Redux, RxDart, scoped_model, just lifting state up, ... and 100 more structure i don't know and can't get to grasp.

What are recommended structures for my use case/What are the pros and cons of different approaches.

**My situation/ use case:** (If I include unrelevant information i'm sorry)

My team and I want to build an potentially "large-scale" app for Android and IOS with flutter and maybe implement this also as a web application.

We will be using Google Firestore as a Database and in our use Case we often like to utilize streams, as there can potentially be many changes from other users for the elements of the current users page.

Until now we just did some prototyping, but now want to really have an structured approach to developing. Also we want to emphasize testing, which we didn't really until now.
Additionally we want to have internationalization, probably with the intl package.

I heard in certain structures code could also be used for a web app in dart, which would be really beneficial, as we potentially want to create an web app in the future.

**Backstory/more optional insight**
So me and my group are a startup in Germany and just won a price in our category in a big national competition.

Our Idee is a digital school assistant, where in a nutshell students create/join courses, where one can place homework, Dates/Events and files into the course. Once created, content will be directly synchronized with the other students in this course.
So for example if a user would be on the homework page, and if another user creates a homework, then the first user should see the new homework directly, without needing to swipe to refresh for example. So i think streams probably, right?

At the moment we are only 6 people, where 4 can develop in flutter, me included ;).
So atm we are only a small team, and have no tests, code-reviews etc.

After the winning, with the help of our prototype, I am now responsible to create a structure for our app, which should be scalable to a big team and many users (maybe from different countries).

Also like I said we may want to implement an web app in the future, with the same functionalities as the app.

***I hope someone could help me, I would be very grateful :).***

Comment: Good questions but not a good fit for StackOverflow - it's way too broad and answers will be strongly opinionated. I'd suggest to ask in https://gitter.im/flutter/flutter or https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/flutter-dev

Comment: Pretty sure this is off-topic here

Comment: One paint point is that there are 2 different Firebase client library implementations for Web and mobile because the web implementation maps to the JS implementation and the mobile ones to Android/iOS native. Currently you need to use your own Firebase abstraction to be able to share as much code as possible between Web and mobile.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Okay, sorry for that, thank you for your advice :)